# When doing fopen PHP makes a copy of the file to itself?

Tags: php, yii2

Anyone can explain to me how exactly this code works.

My doubt is if I delete the file how can I still get a correct download with the deleted file.

PHP, when we do a `fopen`, saves a copy of the file anywhere?

```
$response = Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file, 'download-file.zip');
// Before I send a response I delete the file.
unlink($file);
// Works without issues. The file is downloaded.
return $response;
```

Just a note about what sendFile does.

```
// Yii in sendFile does a fopen and sends the file as stream
$handle = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
$this->sendStreamAsFile($handle, $attachmentName, $options);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works due to the way linux handles file removal. The data remains accessible until the last handle is closed.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove

> If the name was the last link to a file, but any processes still have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed.

This approach works on Windows too since PHP 7.3.0, but the file name remains in use until the last handle is closed.